# How to display separate console on a custom view?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, console, eclipse-rcp

I have created my custom view and put console onto it with the help of `TextConsoleViewer` viewer.

It appeared on my view, but it also appeared on main console view, which is also present on layout.

How to avoid this? How to put console on my view only or, may be, it is possible to hide unneeded console on console view?

The code for view part:

```
public class ChatView extends ViewPart {

    public static final String ID = "com.scisbo.eclipse.programw.ChatView";

    private ShellMod shell;

    private TextConsoleViewer textConsoleViewer;

    @Override
    public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {

        ConsoleFinderService consoleFinderService = (ConsoleFinderService) PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getService(ConsoleFinderService.class);
        MessageConsole console = consoleFinderService.findConsole("Chat");

        textConsoleViewer = new TextConsoleViewer(parent, console);

        shell = new ShellMod(
                new PrintStream(console.newMessageStream()), 
                new PrintStream(console.newMessageStream())
                );

    }

    @Override
    public void setFocus() {
        textConsoleViewer.getControl().setFocus();
    }

}
```

the code for console finder service

```
public class ConsoleFinderService {

    public MessageConsole findConsole(String name) {
        ConsolePlugin plugin = ConsolePlugin.getDefault();
        IConsoleManager conMan = plugin.getConsoleManager();
        IConsole[] existing = conMan.getConsoles();
        for (int i = 0; i < existing.length; i++)
            if (name.equals(existing[i].getName()))
                return (MessageConsole) existing[i];
        // no console found, so create a new one
        MessageConsole myConsole = new MessageConsole(name, null);
        conMan.addConsoles(new IConsole[] { myConsole });
        return myConsole;
    }
}
```

Comment: Add screen shots for better understanding

Answer (score -1):

Don't add the console to the console manager. 
(If you do need a manager, you might want to implement a separate one.)